# Can elemental silicon react with water at room temperature and pressure?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, water

Free silicon is not found in nature (in water, it might be present in the form Si(OH)4). So how is Si(OH)4 formed?
Is there any possibilities of direct reaction with water?

Comment: The bonds $\ce{Si-O-H}$ are formed when silica $\ce{SiO_2}$ is dissolved into hot NaOH, producing a solution containing silicate ions like $\ce{SiO_3^{2-}}$ and $\ce{SiO_4^{4-}}$. In the presence of acidic solution the $\ce{H^+}$ ions are attached to the oxygen atoms of these ions producing $\ce{Si-O-H}$ bonds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is variable information in textbooks about the reaction of silicon with water. Unlike all common allotropic forms of carbon, silicon surface or dust can react with water at elevated temperatures to form oxide layer or orthosilic acid.

> Oxidation of Silicon by High-Pressure Steam by  Joseph R. Ligenza [Original Paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1.2425359/meta)
>
> ABSTRACT: The oxidation of silicon by high-pressure steam was studied
> at temperatures between 773 K and 1123 K and pressures from 25 to 500
> atm. Within a certain range of pressure and temperature a uniform film
> of amorphous silicon dioxide forms. At moderate pressures the film
> growth is linear in time and directly proportional to the steam
> pressure. At higher pressures the kinetics for film formation are
> complicated by the volatility of silica in steam, and, above a certain
> large pressure for any temperature, no film will grow. In the linear
> range, the rate depends on the orientation of the silicon surface and
> is greater for silicon that is phosphorus doped near the degenerate
> range than for high-purity material.

Comment: And steam oxidation is routinely used in silicon semiconductor manufacturing, and has been for 60+ years now. Although one does not get ultra-high purity steam from water, but instead from burning semiconductor grade hydrogen and oxygen.

Comment: I also read that steam vaporizes silicon. What goes on in that process?

Comment: Unless it is very high temperature (greater than 1000C), or unusual conditions, I’m not sure it does. It certainly is not an issue in silicon fabs.